# Moto e - flashed stock firmware but bootloader message says "Software Status: modified"

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, motorola, motorola-moto-e

I have a motoE 2 LTE (XT1514 Surnia) that originally had Android 5.0.2, but it went to motorola for repair and came back with 6.0. Despite the upgrade, the bootloader screen still showed "software status: official".

Then I have unlocked the bootloader, installed [TRWP](https://twrp.me/) and used it to flash supersu. The log says the process was successful but I checked with the app root checker that it was not.

Then I wanted to go back with the stock ROM. I downloaded the XT1514_SURNIA_RETBR_DS_6.0_MPI24.65-39_cid12_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml ROM from this [link](http://www.filefactory.com/folder/752fdb49361c7f62/?sort=filename&order=ASC&show=100&page=2) I found on xda-developers and flashed it using RSD Lite. The system works but the bootloader screen now says "software status: modified"; before this process I made a backup using TWRP but after restoring the bakcup image the message still didn't change back to "software status: official".

I thought maybe I need to install the original Android (5.02) and then upgrade it to 6.0, so I downloaded the XT1514_SURNIA_RETBR_DS_5.0.2_LXI22.50-53.8_cid12_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml ROM from the same link. The problem is I get a failure message when I try to flash the 5.0.2 image

```
    # mfastboot flash partition gpt.bin
    target max-sparse-size: 256MB
    sending 'partition' (32 KB)...
    OKAY [  0.125s]
    writing 'partition'...
    (bootloader) Preflash validation failed
    FAILED (remote failure)
    finished. total time: 0.570s
```

I did try with RSD Lite too, but I get the same message. I've read somewhere you can't dowgrade stock firmware, is this the problem here ? Is there any workaround ?

My final objective is to have stock firmware with android 6.0 installed and the bootloader message saying it is official. I appreciate any help =)

this is the log of RSD Lite flashing the stock image with android 6.0

```
    28/16 05:39:10  The FlashLog key is turned off.
    09/28/16 05:39:10  Multi upgrade started for 1 phones
    09/28/16 05:39:10  [Device ID: 0] 1/20 getvar max-sparse-size
    09/28/16 05:39:10  [Device ID: 0] 2/20 oem fb_mode_set
    09/28/16 05:39:10  [Device ID: 0] 3/20 flash partition "gpt.bin"
    09/28/16 05:39:11  [Device ID: 0] 4/20 flash bootloader "bootloader.img"
    09/28/16 05:39:12  [Device ID: 0] 5/20 flash logo "logo.bin"
    09/28/16 05:39:12  [Device ID: 0] 6/20 flash boot "boot.img"
    09/28/16 05:39:15  [Device ID: 0] 7/20 flash recovery "recovery.img"
    09/28/16 05:39:18  [Device ID: 0] 8/20 flash system "system.img_sparsechunk.0"
    09/28/16 05:39:42  [Device ID: 0] 9/20 flash system "system.img_sparsechunk.1"
    09/28/16 05:40:03  [Device ID: 0] 10/20 flash system "system.img_sparsechunk.2"
    09/28/16 05:40:22  [Device ID: 0] 11/20 flash system "system.img_sparsechunk.3"
    09/28/16 05:40:42  [Device ID: 0] 12/20 flash system "system.img_sparsechunk.4"
    09/28/16 05:40:49  [Device ID: 0] 13/20 flash modem "NON-HLOS.bin"
    09/28/16 05:40:54  [Device ID: 0] 14/20 erase modemst1
    09/28/16 05:40:54  [Device ID: 0] 15/20 erase modemst2
    09/28/16 05:40:54  [Device ID: 0] 16/20 flash fsg "fsg.mbn"
    09/28/16 05:40:54  [Device ID: 0] 17/20 erase carrier
    09/28/16 05:40:55  [Device ID: 0] 18/20 erase cache
    09/28/16 05:40:55  [Device ID: 0] 19/20 erase userdata
    09/28/16 05:40:57  [Device ID: 0] 20/20 oem fb_mode_clear
    09/28/16 05:40:57  [Device ID: 0] reboot
    09/28/16 05:40:57  CMultiFlashFlex::RebootPhone, waiting for phone to disconnect, status=2, state=0.
    09/28/16 05:40:58  Removal, interface=28(0x0), device id=1636460.
    09/28/16 05:40:58  CMultiFlashFlex::RebootPhone, waiting for phone to connect, status=3, state=4.
    09/28/16 05:48:08  00002de8 Phone.cpp   1571    0   ERROR   Waiting for phone's handle is setted successfully after restart [430000 ms] completion. failed
    09/28/16 05:48:08  CMultiFlashFlex::RebootPhone, unable to wait for phone, status=3, state=4.
    09/28/16 05:48:08  [Device ID: 0] Please manually power up this phone.
    09/28/16 05:55:18  00002de8 Phone.cpp   3974    -1  ERROR   CPhone::WaitForPhone timed out. Iteration-1
    09/28/16 05:55:18  [Device ID: 0] Please manually power up this phone.
    09/28/16 06:02:28  00002de8 Phone.cpp   3974    -1  ERROR   CPhone::WaitForPhone timed out. Iteration-2
    09/28/16 06:02:28  [Device ID: 0] Please manually power up this phone.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  Arrival, interface=36(0x0), device id=1636460.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  [Device ID: 0] Waiting for others to finish current operation.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  Arrival, interface=20(0x0), device id=1636460.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  Arrival, interface=19(0x0), device id=1636460.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  The FlashLog key is turned off.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  FlashLog file is turned off.
    09/28/16 06:08:36  Multi upgrade finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader showing the "Modified" status is normal in your situation, since you've unlocked the bootloader and flashed TWRP, then used TWRP to flash a ROM.  Motorola won't allow a downgrade like you are doing (at least in my experiences w/ them, so 6.0 to 5.0.2), so your best bet is to try and get the 6.0 factory image for your device, and flash that with RSD Lite, then see what the bootloader says after that.

Comment: Hi, @RMarkwald, I did get a 6.0 factory that I could successfully flashed, I got it from a link in xda-developer forum. But the message still shows "Software status: modified"

Comment: A weird thing is there is a supersu folder at the root folder that keeps being recreated even if I flash a new image, although the phone is not rooted. Do you think this may be the problem ?

Comment: How are you flashing it, RSD Lite or via TWRP Recovery?  Nevermind, I see those are files used for RSD Lite.

Comment: I tryed both methods, but got same results. Even the original backup I made and restored with TWRP didn't change the "Software Status" message back to "official"

Comment: You will never get back to `Software Status: Official`,  once the bootloader has been unlocked and anything has been modified, it can never be returned to a status of `Official`. Your bootloader status will also always show its been unlocked and can never be returned to a state of `0`

Comment: acejavelin, I thought so also. But look at this video at times 1:10 and 11:20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3MDo6EXoDc

Comment: @Gus TBH, he just got lucky using the old version/OTA method, we have been trying to figure out any consistent way to get back to Official for some time on XDA. The only success that has been seen is hit and miss at best, is install an older firmware via fastboot and relock, then take an OTA, it's about a 1 in 3 chance of changing to official status. Note that even if you relock the bootloader, the Bootloader Status Code can never go back to 0.

Comment: @acejavelin can I still receive security updates from motorola with software status modified ?

Comment: @Gus Yes, of course... as long as you have a stock phone the OTA and other updates don't care if your bootloader is unlocked or what the software status says in the bootloader, it will check to see if /system has been modified and attempt to apply to the update which requires stock recovery, otherwise the update doesn't care. This may or may not set you back to "Official" software status, we have yet to figure out what it is changing the few times it does work, it is extremely inconsistent.